# Databricks pyspark, Difference in result of Dataframe.count() and Display(Dataframe) while using header='false'

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am reading CSV (present on Azure datalake store) file in dataframe by following code:

```
df = spark.read.load(filepath, format="csv", schema = mySchema, header="false", mode="DROPMALFORMED");
```

File *filepath* contain 100 rows and header. I want to ignore header from file while reading so I defined `header="false"` . (As sometimes file come with header and sometimes not)

After reading in dataframe when I display dataframe by display(df) statement I got all the data and showed 100 rows which is correct. But when I used to check count of dataframe by using df.count() It displayed me 101 rows. Does dataframe show count with header? or Am I missing something?

*mySchema* and *filepath* already separately defined in cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `mode="DROPMALFORMED"` while reading csv file.

- When there are some malformed records spark **drops them out** in **`df.show() but counts them in df.count().`**
- In your case as header is false and schema specified so spark reads data as per your specified types if there are issues then records will not be shown

**`Example:`**

```
#sample data
#cat employee.csv
#id,name,salary,deptid
#1,a,1000,101
#2,b,2000,201

ss=StructType([StructField("id",IntegerType()),StructField("name",StringType()),StructField("salary",StringType()),StructField("deptid",StringType())])

df=spark.read.load("employee.csv",format="csv",schema=ss,header="false",mode="DROPMALFORMED")


df.show()
#+---+----+------+------+
#| id|name|salary|deptid|
#+---+----+------+------+
#|  1|   a|  1000|   101|
#|  2|   b|  2000|   201|
#+---+----+------+------+

#issue in df.count
df.count()
#3 #has to be 2
```

**`To Fix:`**

Add **`notNull`** filter while reading as dataframe.

```
df=spark.read.load("employee.csv",format="csv",schema=ss,header="false",mode="DROPMALFORMED").filter(col("id").isNotNull())

df.show()
#+---+----+------+------+
#| id|name|salary|deptid|
#+---+----+------+------+
#|  1|   a|  1000|   101|
#|  2|   b|  2000|   201|
#+---+----+------+------+

#fixed count
df.count()
#2
```

To view malformed data **remove mode**:

```
spark.read.load("employee.csv",format="csv",schema= mySchema,header="false").show(100,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the pyspark documentation,

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader

```
header – uses the first line as names of columns. If None is set, it uses the default value, false.
```

You might need to standardize the way you get your data, either with headers or without headers, and then set the flag.

If you set header=False, then the spark engine will simply read the first row as a data row.

To answer your question, Dataframe count does not count header.
I would recommend reading the data first and then dropping the headers for debugging purposes.

Also, `display(df)` is a python operation provided by Ipython, I would use `dataframe.show()` which a spark provided utility for debugging purposes.